# Write to terminal environment from bash or node

Tags: linux, bash, build, environment-variables, npm-scripts

### The Goal

I want to write a script that will prompt the user for a few pieces of information, IE size, shape, color, which it will then put on **that terminal's environment**. Perhaps most importantly I also want to run this script from within an npm script.

### Example

package.json

```
"scripts":{
   "fillVars": "source theThing.bs",
   "echoVarsHoursLater": "echo $theSize" //etc
}
```

theThing.bs

```
read -p "Size: " theSize
read -p "Shape: " theShape
read -p "Color: " theColor
```

### Notes

And I would then want those env vars to be available to any scripts or code run afterwards from the same terminal. NOT JUST from within that script. also NOT from anywhere in the os if possible (aka other terminals or sessions).

I know if I just source theThing.bs directly in the terminal I can get it working. But I can't figure out how to get past the npm script part.

This is largely a convenience tool, but it's a really helpful one for this process.

Comment: It's not possible to change the environment of another process.

Comment: Processes (including shells) have environments, but terminals don't. Programs that appear to have per-terminal settings instead pass a single, unmodified environment variable that tells you where to find your information (`ssh-agent`, X11) or look up the information in a known file based on the tty name (`sudo`, `sem`)

Comment: @that other guy By "terminal" they apparently mean the top-level interactive shell in the terminal. Also, modern software based "terminal" emulators most definitely do have an environment include env vars. It's only ancient hardware terminals like a Televideo 950 for which that makes no sense.

Comment: That's like saying a hard drive has an environment if you use a graphical file manager. Dont confuse the PTY and its controlling process.

Answer (score 0):

The UNIX environment model makes what you are doing impossible without the cooperation of the parent process. A child process cannot, for security reasons, directly manipulate the environment of its parent and that includes its env vars. The usual solution is for the child process to write a sequence of shell statements that set the env vars and have the parent shell "eval" the command. For example, if you wrote a shell script named `my_env_init` which did

```
echo export MY_SIZE=42
```

You would tell the user to type

```
eval $(my_env_init)
```

What you're trying to do is basically impossible when you have arbitrary layers in the middle like an NPM program. As it too would have to collect the commands written by your env setting script and echo those to the top-level shell. You're going about this the wrong way but no one will be able to provide a proper answer because your question doesn't adequately explain why you're trying to do this.